# How APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT works to provide better performance than count function in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

How APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT actually works to get better performance and why the count we get from this function is not accurate?
Does it use HASH GROUP BY internally?

Comment: I think you have to ask the oracle engineers that question. It would be part of their proprietary code.  What would you do differently if you had the answer?

Comment: It's not about what I would do differently. Its curiosity that I have. What would you differently if you know earth revolves around sun but still you know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2014-08-scaling-cardinality-estimates-12102 we can find that it uses HyperLogLog algorithm and it also gives a link to its' description on Alex Fatkulin's blog: http://afatkulin.blogspot.com/2013/11/hyperloglog-in-oracle.html

PS. RIP Alex... Hopefully his articles are still alive...